# Removing last character with Javascript or jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the below code that is trying (unsuccessfully) to remove the last comma from the outputted string below.

```
       jQuery(function($){
            var string = "{image : 'melbourne.jpg'},{image : 'tunnel.jpg'},{image : 'building.jpg'},"; 

            $.supersized({
                slide_interval          :   3000, 
                slides                  :   [ string.substring(0, string.length - 1) ]
            });
        });
```

But what I need is this:

```
 jQuery(function($){
            var string = "{image : 'melbourne.jpg'},{image : 'tunnel.jpg'},{image : 'building.jpg'},"; 

            $.supersized({
                slide_interval          :   3000, 
                slides                  :   [ {image : 'melbourne.jpg'},{image : 'tunnel.jpg'},{image : 'building.jpg'} ]
            });
        });
```

I've tried a heap of different things, but to no avail. I'm not sure what I am doing wrong!!

Comment: You didn't escape your string properly, see the incorrect syntax highlighting? Also, where are you getting that string from? I would start tracking the problem there, that comma shouldn't be there from the start.

Comment: I've fixed that up above. I'm using Business Catalyst and the string is being built by single items coming in dynamically from the database

Comment: If you get that last comma, somewhere in your code something went wrong. Instead of removing it you should track down the culprit... But the question is why is the string retrieved this way? You should use a format both server and client can understand, such as JSON. You're basically re-inventing the wheel here, and it'll bite you later. I'm not sure how this Business Catalyst works though...

Answer (score 1):

You are correct about your `str.substring(0, str.length - 1);`

But you didn't create your string object `var string = '{image : 'melbourne.jpg'},{image : 'tunnel.jpg'},{image : 'building.jpg'},';` correctly.  First, you don't want quotes around it.  Secondly, it is malformed.  Thirdly, listen to  elclanrs!

Answer (score 0):

Don't pass data like that using string, using javascript objects.

```
   jQuery(function($){
        var slides = [{image : 'melbourne.jpg'},
                      {image : 'tunnel.jpg'},
                      {image : 'building.jpg'}]; 

        $.supersized({
            slide_interval          :   3000, 
            slides                  :   slides
        });
    });
```

You may say that string comes from the server side, then you should fix the data in the server side let it could be parse to be an javascript object.

**But if you do not listen to my advise and stick to that string, you may touch the `eval` evil.**

```
   jQuery(function($){
        var string = "{image : 'melbourne.jpg'},{image : 'tunnel.jpg'},{image : 'building.jpg'},"; 

        $.supersized({
            slide_interval          : 3000, 
            slides                  : eval("["+string.substring(0, string.length - 1)+"]")
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to process your data first:

```
var imageStr = "{image : 'melbourne.jpg'},{image :'tunnel.jpg'},{image :'building.jpg'},";
imageStr = imageStr.substring(0, imageStr.length - 1)

imagesArray = imageStr.split(',');

var jsonObj;
var imageList = [];

for(var i = 0; i < imagesArray.length; i++){
    jsonObj = eval("("+imagesArray[i]+")");
imageList.push(jsonObj);    
}

var data = JSON.stringify(imageList);
```

After processing, you may then use the **data** variable as such:

```
slider: data
```

Comment: You have to know `[ string.substring(0, string.length - 1) ]` will not create the expected array for you.

Comment: No errors, the slider just displays its loading gif and no images display (obviously :)